# How to close all instances of chrome in bash

Tags: bash

I have a very simple script that opens two tabs in chrome, how would i then close these two tabs? Ive tried a few "kill" lines, but nothing is working.

```
start "" http://www.site1.com
start "" http://www.site2.com
```

Comment: Try this: `killall chrome`

Comment: Have you tried `pkill` command? What do you see for these processes in the output of `ps`?

Comment: i tried both of these, the windows opened but did not close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an option could be to save the PID of the process then use the kill command to terminate the process.

```
#!/bin/bash

start "" http://www.site1.com & export pidChrome1=$!
#I guess you do something here so you can add a sleep 
kill -TERM $pidChrome1 #or you can use kill -9
```

Regards

Claudio

Comment: Depends on the script. It is very likely that `start` opens the page as a background job, possibly doing other stuff as well. It may make more sense to get the pid as a return value from the `start` function.

Comment: @Shahbaz you're right, maybe it's better to remove the & for background then save the PID, and after some operations kill the process

Comment: i tried the kill -TERM and that didnt seem to work. Could you show me what the above comments  might look at